# Нужно, чтобы картинка менялась при нажатии на нее

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте!  Какой код в файле js нужно написать, чтобы при нажатии на картинку hello.png  картинка менялась на world.png (который в той же папке, что и hello.png). Нужно, чтобы потом при повторном нажатии картинка возращалась на hello.png.

```js
function oClick(e) {
  var element = document.getElementById("f2");
  if (element.style.backgroundImage) {
    element.style.backgroundImage = null; // clean up for next click
  } else {
    element.style.backgroundImage = "url('img/hell.jpg')"; // set new value
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="pic/hello.png" id="myPic">
```

Пробовал на подобие этой функции, но у меня просто картинка пропадает и при повторном нажатии ничего не происходит.

Comment: А что Вы думаете по этому поводу? Какие сложности у Вас возникли?

Comment: Выше ответил, посмотрите

Comment: а почему backgroundImage ? не лучше ли element.src ?

Comment: это просто пример из другой задачи, но принцип такой же. Просто в моем примере меняется сама картинка, а в этом примере фон меняется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var foto = ['https://cdn.wallaps.com/wallpapers/10000/2870.jpg',
  'http://fnips.ru/wall/7/leopard_trava_bezhat_bolshaya_koshka_1920x1200.jpg'
]
document.querySelector('img').src = foto[0];
document.querySelector('img').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (this.src == foto[1]) {
    this.src = foto[0];
  } else {
    this.src = foto[1];
  }
})
```

```css
img {
  width: 170px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img src="">
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var img = document.getElementById("myPic");
    
img.onclick = function(event){
  var target = event.target;
  if (target.className == "hello") {
    target.src = "https://via.placeholder.com/250/?text=world";
    target.className = "world";
  } else if(target.className == "world") {
    target.src = "https://via.placeholder.com/250/?text=Hello";
    target.className = "hello";
  } 
}
```

```html
<img class="hello" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250/?text=Hello"  id="myPic">
```

Перед запуском кода, добавьте картинке класс `hello`

Comment: Задание элементарное. Если по таким вопросам будете спрашивать весь код - так Вы JS не выучите

Comment: А обязательно классы использовать в данному случае, id не подходит?

Comment: можно использовать, что угодно. Но тогда код надо переписывать.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код содержит такую логику где вы устанавливаете в качестве фона изображение для элемента `img`, который уже отрисовывает картинку. Таким образом ваше фоновое изображение будет находится под существующим.

Для изменения фона нужно использовать подход без использования элемента img.
Создайте `div`, в css пропишите `background-image`, а с помощью js изменяйте его по нажатию.

Посмотрите на пример кода ниже.

```js
var firstBgImage = 'http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/ff0000';
var secondBgImage = 'http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/00ffff';
var firstBgImageUrl = 'url("' + firstBgImage + '")';
var secondBgImageUrl = 'url("' + secondBgImage + '")';

function clickOnDiv(e) {
  if (e.style.backgroundImage == firstBgImageUrl)
    e.style.backgroundImage = secondBgImageUrl;
  else
    e.style.backgroundImage = firstBgImageUrl;
}
```

```css
#myPic {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/ff0000");
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head></head> 
    <body>
      <div id="myPic" onclick="clickOnDiv(this)"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Плохой тон, писать в `onclick` - `javascript:`.

Comment: Спасибо, убрал.

Comment: Лучше бы, просто, сделать +1 к комменту.