# Как лучше заменять изображение в теге img из объекта Image?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Допустим, на странице есть простой тег img:

```
<img src="img/1.png" alt="" class="img">
```

Затем в скрипте я создаю новый объект изображения, и загружаю в него другую картинку.

```
var newImg = new Image();
newImg.src = "img/2.png";
```

Но как правильнее будет заменить имеющуюся на странице картинку новой, чтобы не вызвать повторную загрузку этой картинки?

UPD. (Дополню) Если делать самым очевидным способом - присвоением src, то все работает, но иногда(далеко не всегда) происходят новые запросы на получение картинки. Сервер на них отвечает кодом 304, загрузки при этом не происходит, но факт лишнего запроса остается. Если такие замены будут происходить часто, и их на странице будет несколько, то возможны потенциальные проблемы.
Еще вариант с удалением изначальной картинки, и вставки на ее место новой из объекта:

```
var img = $('.img');
var parent = img.parent();
img.remove();
parent.append(newImg);
```

Таким способом лишних запросов не происходит вообще, но минус в том, что если были повешены события на изначальную картинку, то они слетят

Comment: А объект зачем? В чем смысл? Можно просто поменять `src`

Comment: прсмотри пример тут  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/758775/Нужно-чтобы-картинка-менялась-при-нажатии-на-нее/759013#759013

Comment: Не все так просто :( Картинка будет меняться много раз. При этом если заменять просто src, браузер периодически пытается проверить, не изменилась ли картинка, и посылает лишние запросы к серверу. Я пытаюсь как раз этого избежать

Comment: А что тебе мешало это описать  сразу в вопросе?

Comment: > Но как правильнее будет заменить имеющуюся на странице картинку новой, чтобы не вызвать повторную загрузку этой картинки?

Comment: я бы тебе предложил сразу всю суть описать....  Опиши вопрос более подробно и получешь более внятный ответ... Какой сервер, что за запросы, в каких случаях и на кой меняется картинка?.....

Comment: любой src это запрос. Вы кешировать хотите или где?

Comment: По сути да, кеширование в объект

Comment: Чтобы не совершать лишних запросов, надо правильно выставить заголовки кеширования, после чего можно спокойно менять src.

Answer (score 0):

Объект **`Image`** вернёт готовый **`img`** тег, у вас же надо просто заменить ссылку на картинку:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('button');

function changeSrc(img) {
    var image = document.getElementById(img).src = 'https://www.tenstickers.co.uk/wall-stickers/img/preview/one-love-rasta-wall-sticker-10261.png';
}
```

```css
img{width:200px}
```

```html
<button id="button" onclick="changeSrc('img-x')">click</button>
<img id="img-x" src="https://img00.deviantart.net/5e03/i/2010/195/e/f/rasta_homer_by_djog.png" alt="" class="img">
```

Comment: Весь смысл в том, чтобы не отсылать лишних запросов, а такой способ их периодически генерирует

Comment: @Neyasbltb_88 ? ? ? ? ?

Comment: Я не пойму точную систему, когда это происходит, но если оставляю на некоторое время такую замену по интервалу, то вижу, что иногда происходят повторные запросы картинки. Возможно это из-за того, что перехожу на другую вкладку, а потом по возвращении это происходит, или еще какие-то причины. Я пробовал удалять полностью изначальный img, и на его место вставлять из объекта, так не происходит повторных запросов, но, естественно, слетят события, повешенные на оригинальную img

Comment: @Neyasbltb_88 А как происходит замена ссылки на картинку? Какое событие отвечает за смену?

Comment: Я хочу сделать что-то вроде анимации, пока просто интервалом